# checkbox jquery using ajax to send data and save in php not inserting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, checkbox, mysqli

I tried to serialize rather to push the elements value but still I get the array with inserting each value 9 times in database. please anyone to help me figure out my problem this is what I am trying to

The HTML:

```
    <form name="chkl" id="chkl" method="post">  
                
<input type="checkbox" class="get_value" name="chk1[ ]" value="<?php echo $rows['ID'];?>">&nbsp<?php echo $rows['DESCRIPTION'];?></input><br>

<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="chk1" value="Submit">
```

JS:

```
<script>
 $('#chk1').click(function(){  
$('input[type=checkbox]').each( function() {
          $.post('fee_checked_save.php', $( ".get_value" ).serialize(), function(data){
          if(data == 1){
             $('#result').html(data);  
          }
      });
});
});
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php  
    
  $checkbox1 = $_POST['chk1'];
    if(isset($_POST['chk1']))  
    {  
    for ($i=0; $i<count ($checkbox1);$i++) {  
    $query = "INSERT INTO fee_checked(FEE_ID) VALUES ('".$checkbox1[$i]. "')";  
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    }  
    echo "Record is inserted";  
    }  
    ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending all checkbox value but , i think you need to only send checkbox which is `checked` so use `:checked` then you have use `$( ".get_value" ).serialize()` this is targetting all class that's why you are seeing mutliple insert instead change that to `$(this).serialize()` . I have added other way as well instead of sending checkbox ony by one you can use `$(this).closest("form").serialize()` to send whole form datas at onces.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$('#chk1').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()

  //send only input which is checked
  $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).serialize())
    //use `this` here,,
    $.post('fee_checked_save.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        $('#result').html(data);
      }
    });
  });
});

//prefer way : 
$('#chk1').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("from second way.." + $(this).closest("form").serialize())
  $.post('fee_checked_save.php', $(this).closest("form").serialize(), function(data) {
    //some codes
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="chkl" id="chkl" method="post">

  <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" name="chk1[]" value="1">&nbsp; Soemthings..
  <input type="checkbox" class="get_value" name="chk1[]" value="2">&nbsp; Soemthings..


  <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="chk1" value="Submit">
</form>
```